# HTML Email Template Clickable Area

Tags: html, email, anchor, mailchimp

Slightly confusing issue that is probably blatantly obvious to solve..

I have a mailchimp template that I'm using to send campaign emails. The template builder has default buttons that can be customised.

Except the anchor is being used only on the text inside the button. Which is limiting the clickable area to just the text element.Is there anyway to apply a simple fix to apply to make the outer class clickable? I have tried wrapping an anchor tag around the outer TD but this does not resolve the issue.

```
                <tbody>
                    <tr>

                            <td align="center" valign="middle" class="mcnButtonContent" style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 16px; padding: 20px;">
                                <a class="mcnButton " title="    Confirm Email    " href="URL" target="_blank" style="font-weight: bold;letter-spacing: normal;line-height: 100%;text-align: center;">    Confirm Email    </a>
                       </td>

                    </tr>
                </tbody>
```

Thanks for your help,

D

Comment: Making the a-tag a block-element should do the trick (display: block)

Comment: No such luck with that unfortunately

Comment: add width and height to ur a tag

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it like this:

```
<tr>
  <td align="center" valign="middle" class="mcnButtonContent" style="font-family:Arial;font-size:16px;padding: 0;">
    <a class="mcnButton " title="Reply" href="{{replyLink}}" target="_blank" style="font-weight:bold;letter-spacing:normal;line-height:100%;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;color:#ffffff;word-wrap:break-word;display: block;margin: 0;padding: 16px;">Reply</a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

The key is to remove the padding from the `td` element and make the `a` grow to fill the table cell. A combination of `display:block` and `padding` on the `a` did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make an entire table cell/row a link, it's best to use JavaScript's `onclick` function:

`<a onclick="document.location ='http://www.google.com'"class="mcnButton " title="    Confirm Email    " href="URL" target="_blank" style="font-weight: bold;letter-spacing: normal;line-height: 100%;text-align: center;">    Confirm Email    </a>`